# word-wrap attribute is not supported in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I am having issues wrapping some words in the item list.

I have converted item list into `XSLT` page. Tried setting column `width` to some value but it gets overridden and stretched out as cells contain some long words without spaces. I tried adding `word-wrap: break-word;` as inline styling, but it is instantly marked red with message:

> This property is marked invalid because it's not supported by the
>   current schema.

If I save the page anyways it works how it's supposed to work, but if I navigate somewhere else from current list, everything resets and I am back to square one.

How do I fix this? Is there some global CSS which would enable the use of `word-wrap`? In essence, I want word wrapping in cells of standard view. Even of long space-less words.

Comment: Always annoying when software thinks it knows better than you. :-(

Comment: Show your code please. The error message you receive should be possible to use within an xslt schema afaik, so you've probably made an error somewhere.

Comment: I made it work somehow by setting width of individual message boxes.